# Vectorized version of numel within a certain moving range

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have something similar to the following which counts the number of elements in a certain range:

```
N = 10000;
%// Setup arrays, only included here to be a working example (slow, does not matter)
x = 1:N;
y = [];
for i=1:N/10 y=[y,1:10]; end
%// Find number of x elements in a certain range for each n
window=500;
step=100;
for n=1:10
    temp = x(y==n); % filter x for each n in y
    %// Instead of the below for loop ...
    %//j=1;
    %//for i=window:step:N-window
    %//  num(j,n) = numel(find(temp>i-window & temp<i));
    %//  j=j+1;
    %//end
    %// this vectorized version ...
    num(:,n) = sum(bsxfun(@gt,temp,(0:step:N-window)')' ...
                   & bsxfun(@lt,temp,(window:step:N)')');
end
```

I am first, filtering data `x` by indices in `y`. Then for each of these `y`, counting the number of elements in a range which is a moving window.

Not sure how I could go about vectorizing this I can't pass vectors to find for example like `find(temp>[1:10] & temp<[5:15])`.

Comment: I think you could provide a better explanation as to what your code does, but it is probably faster to do `sum(temp>i-window & temp<i)` than `numel(find(temp>i-window & temp<i))` and that is easily vectorizable

Comment: @Dan Thanks, indeed that is better, however I still can't do something similar to `sum(temp>[1:10] & temp<[5:15])` though for example.

Comment: `temp>[1:10]` could be written like `bsxfun(@gt, temp, (1:10)')`...

Comment: numel(find(X)) == nnz(X)

Comment: @Dan I didn't know about `bsxfun`, great, that has vectorized my inner loop for a great start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step # 1:** `temp = x(y==n)`

You are performing [`logical indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to select elements from `x` at `"x(y==n)"`, which are stored as `temp`. Then, you are using `temp` and performing comparisons on it and counting them. As such, `temp` would have variable number of elements, which is not conducive for vectorization. So, we must try to keep a 2D mask of `equalities` for all `n`'s at `y==n` with `bsxfun(eq`.

**Step # 2:** `temp>i-window & temp<i`

Next up, we have `"(temp>i-window & temp<i)"`, for which we can use `bsxfun` again with `bsxfun(gt` and `bsxfun(lt` to simulate them .

Finally, we are trying to *match* `equality mask` with the `comparison mask`, i.e. steps `1` and `2` and performing counting, for which `matrix-multiplication` would give us a good helping hand.

Thus, the implementation for generic inputs `x` and `y` would be -

```
%// Array version of iterator n : "for n=1:10"
n_arr = 1:10;              

%// Array version of iterator i : "for i=window:step:N-window"
I = window:step:N-window;  

%// Simulate "y==n" (equalities mask) in a vectorized manner
step_mask = bsxfun(@eq,y(:),n_arr);

%// Simulate "(temp>i-window & temp<i)" (comparisons mask) in a vectorized manner
comp_mask = bsxfun(@gt,x(:),I-window) & bsxfun(@lt,x(:),I);

%// Peform selection of elements from x in "x(y==n)" and the counting in
%// one go with powerful matrix-multiplication
num_out = double(comp_mask).'*double(step_mask);
```

Closing comment : When performing `vectorization`, do consider `bsxfun` strongly.